# Will the following code reset and refresh a form after a submit?

Tags: javascript, html

Should the following code work to reset AND refresh a form after it has been submitted? I have a reset button on the form also that works fine if incorrect information is entered, however I would also like to reset and clear the form as well after the form has been submitted. I am still seeing the information on the form after the submit using this code.

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

Here is my current HTML:

```
<form action="celebrantdata.php" method="post" id="weddata">
    <div class="c1">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="style2"    value="Submit" onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)" />
        <input name="Reset" type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" onclick="clearform();"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show your entire form tag.

Comment: Using just html: when posting to itself, the form should default back to it's original values (set in .. well "value" for the form element). Are you using any code to "default the values" to what has been posted?

Comment: No, there are current default values on the form,  It is  a questions and answer type form.

Comment: `<form method='POST' action='what?'>` This is what i'm looking for

Comment: <form action="celebrantdata.php" method="post" id="weddata">

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: had forgotten about the `formObject.reset()` function**

```
var form = document.querySelector('#weddata');
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    form.reset();
}
```

Note that if you plan on supporting older versions of IE, you would have to use the following:

```
var form = document.getElementById('weddata');
if (form.addEventListener)
    form.addEventListener('submit', callback, false); // modern browsers
else if (form.attachEvent)
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', callback); // IE

function callback() {
    form.reset();
}
```

Comment: Note that `useCapture` (the third parameter of the `addEventListener` method), even if it's optional, some browsers still require it (example: Safari, happened to me a while ago). So I would recommend to always set it to false: `obj.addEventListener( 'event', callback, false );`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Safari has recognized the `usecapture` argument as optional for quite a few years now - since 2011, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong). Though, considering I even bothered adding IE support, that's still a completely valid point.

Comment: Probably, but I realized a while ago that my own Javascript didn't work just a couple of months ago (using Safari 8). Maybe it was just a bug, but it's always good to simply use `false` :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván IIRC ``usecapture`` has been an optional arugment since Safari 5.1. Nevertheless, you are correct and I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the following script:

```
function clearForm() {
    var form = arguments[0];
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type == 'text') {
            inputs[i].value = '';
        }
    }
}
```

With the following addition in the form tag:

```
onsubmit="clearForm(this);"
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('weddata').reset();`

Comment: Oops,  My above code certainly clears the form. However, on testing it live, the form is being cleared before the data is submitted.  Is it possible to add a delay?

Comment: Well, forms usually change the website, so no "native" way. You could, however, use a timer that clears it after a while: `onsubmit="setTimeout( function() { document.getElementById('weddate').reset(); }, 100);"`